# Error al crear un proyecto de grails en la version 2.5.0

Tags: tomcat, grails

un saludos cordial, soy nuevo en grails. A la hora de crear un proyecto desde GGTS me surgen estos errores, estoy usando la versión 2.5.0 de grails.

Ya intente con muchos repositorios pero ninguno sin éxito, espero me puedan compartir alguna solución, o aconsejarme cual otra versión me daría menos problemas. gracias de antemano, que tenga un excelente día.

Estos son los errores que me surgen:

```
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not transfer artifact org.grails.plugins:tomcat:zip:7.0.55.2 from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:zip:2.1.5, org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:zip:4.3.8.1, org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:zip:2.0-RC4, org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ldap:zip:2.0-RC2, org.grails.plugins:quartz:zip:1.0.2: Could not transfer artifact org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:zip:2.1.5 from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:zip:2.1.5, org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:zip:4.3.8.1, org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:zip:2.0-RC4, org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ldap:zip:2.0-RC2, org.grails.plugins:quartz:zip:1.0.2: Could not transfer artifact org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:zip:2.1.5 from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:zip:2.1.5, org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:zip:2.0-RC4, org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ldap:zip:2.0-RC2, org.grails.plugins:quartz:zip:1.0.2: Could not transfer artifact org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:zip:2.1.5 from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Error |
Could not transfer artifact org.grails.plugins:tomcat:zip:7.0.55.2 from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
|Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

[image: una pequeña captura de lo que me sale]

Answer (score 0):

Parece [ser un issue](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11825#issuecomment-856250177).

Yo lo resolví en un proyecto en el que uso grails 2.5.6 estableciendo el siguiente código:

En `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsHome()
        mavenRepo url: 'https://repo.grails.org/artifactory/plugins', name: 'grailsCentral'
        mavenRepo "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        mavenRepo 'https://grails.jfrog.io/grails/core/'
        mavenRepo 'https://grails.jfrog.io/grails/plugins/'
        mavenRepo "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/simple/libs-releases-local"
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

Lo que hace el código es definir de manera explícita las urls de los repositorios a los que debe conectarse para descargar las dependencias.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica el funcionamiento de este código: lee [answer].